# Delegates: the preferred way to load them, based on a "status"

Tags: c#-4.0

I had some code which was fairly cumbersome:

```
If custStatus = "PO"
    ContactCustomer(custId, "static string value")
Elseif   custStatus = "BA"
    ContactCustomer(custId, "static string value")
    UpdateCustomer 
 Elseif   custStatus = "CA"
    ContactCustomer(custId, "static string value")
    UpdateCustomer 
Elseif   custStatus = "CA"
     ContactCustomer(custId, "static string value")
     UpdateCustomer 
Elseif   custStatus = "zA"
     ContactCustomer(custId, "static string value")
     UpdateCustomer 
End
```

The above isn't good.I believe that delegates will help make the code a bit more maintainable.Please see my attempt below.However, it still looks cumbersome. I'm trying to solve the problem of having a "variable quantity of delegates", based on the customer status, and was thinking that I could maybe use the status as a "key" in a hashTable, the value of which would be the delegateList..Hopefully I've made sense.

Can anyone suggest a more elegant way to achieve this? ta.

```
    private delegate string MethodDelegate(int custId, string a);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ////Depending on customer status, either call 1 delegate, or call both

        var delList = new List<MethodDelegate> { ContactCustomer, UpdateCustomer }; 
        string custStatus; 
        custStatus = GetCustomerStatus(custId);


        if (custStatus == "PO")
        {
            delList[0]("Say Hello");
        }
        elseif    ("BA") 
        {
            delList[0]("Say Hello Again");
            delList[1](custId, "New Customer Details");
        }
        elseif    ("CA") 
        {
            delList[0]("Say Hello Again");
            delList[1](custId, "New Customer Details");
        }
        else
         {
    //Do nothing
          }
    }

    private static string ContactCustomer(string x)
    {
        return x;
    } 

    private static string UpdateCustomer(custId, string x)
    {
        //STUBBED
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: Are these two cases going to be the only ones? Then I would just use the methods directly. If there will be more states, then I could imagine something like a delegate decorator with a factory. Is the order important?

Comment: No, your 2nd snippet is **not** more readable or maintainable than the 1st snippet.  A *virtual method* would be an improvement.  Although it is pretty unclear what a customer status "PO" might mean.  Probably not "pissed off".  A purchase order is not a customer, it is an entirely separate class.  Writing good code needs to start with good design first.

Comment: hiya,   @Nico: Yes there will be more than 2 states.The order is important.The states that I mention aren't important.Let's say for argument's sake that there are 6 of them.    Why would a virtual method help? Thanks

Comment: I'd agree with @HansPassant. Your 2nd attempt is using delegates because you can, which is never a good reason. Look again at your design & decide what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a dictionary (e.g. Dictionary).

You should then be able to go:

```
 dictionary[custStatus]("say hello")
```

I would also recommend using an enumeration instead of strings for custStatus.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this fits your needs, but you could use a *Strategy* in combination with a *State Machine*:

```
abstract class CustomerState
{
    Customer customer;
    public abstract void PerformAction();

    public CustomerState(Customer c) { this.customer = c; }
}

class POState : CustomerState  //Rename appropriately
{
    public POState(Customer c) : base(c) { }

    public void PerformAction()
    {
        customer.Contact();
    }
}

class BAState : CustomerState  //Rename appropriately
{
    public BAState (Customer c) : base(c) { }

    public void PerformAction()
    {
        customer.Contact();
        customer.Update();
    }
}

class Customer
{
    CustomerState poState = new POState(this);
    CustomerState baState = new BAState(this);

    public CustomerState CurrentState { get; private set; }

    public Customer()
    {
        CurrentState = poState;
    }

    public void Contact() { }
    public void Update() { }
}
```

which you then could use like:

```
Customer c = GetCustomer(customerId);
c.CurrentState.PerformAction();
```

You could also add functionality that maps string states (propably retrieved from a database?) to the state types. E.g. with the help of a factory.

In general it is not very smart to manage important information as strings, if it is actually no string. String are good for storing and displaying information (under certain conditions), but you should transform them to appropriate types when loading them into your application (or via a lazy loading concept).

Comment: I suppose that technically my question was answered, but you're right, I think I need to re-think the design.Thanks to all who took the time to help! yogi